# Why does an electron-donating group reduce the polarity of the O-H bond?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polarity

Why does the polarity of $\ce{O-H}$ bond decrease if an electron-donating group is attached in the compound?

For example, I have seen that when alkyl groups are joined in phenols, the polarity of $\ce{O-H}$ bond in them decreases. Why does that happen?

Comment: How do you know that it decreases?

Comment: It is written in my book.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Because when the akyl group comes and attaches to the ring,since alkyl groups are electron releasing they give their electrons in ring, then the ring does not wants electron that much and so it does not attracts the electron of (O) so the polarisability of (O-H) bond in phenol decreases.